# DJango: Multiple instances of an application in a single project

Tags: django

I have a django application and i've needed to create multiple instances.  So currently i create a virtualenv for each instance with its own django project.  However this is not scaling well.  What i really need is multiple instances of the application inside a single django project.

Is there any sort of examples or advice for something like this?  I was thinking of using multiple databases, but then each db would get all of the models for all applications in the project.

Comment: You're barking up completely the wrong tree here. Multiple instances of an app wouldn't in any way fix your scaling issues. There are plenty of ways to scale Django, but in order to help we need more information about exactly what's happening.

Comment: The "scaling" problem is that i have to make a new virtualenv, django project, database, wsgi service, etc. for every new instance.  This could all be scripted, but it feels like a bad idea when really the differences are config and database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would like to see Multi Tenant Applications in Django.

If you follow this book it contain what you are looking for. [Building Multi Tenant Applications with Django](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/index.html)

Taken from the above shared docs.**(Summary)**

The various approached to multi tenancy

- Shared database with shared schema
- Shared database with isolated schema
- Isolated database with a shared app server
- Completely isolated tenants using Docker

Comment: that looks like what i need.  Thanks!

Comment: The blog post [Multi-Tenancy in Django](https://www.viget.com/articles/multi-tenancy-in-django/) provides an outline for the 'Shared database with shared schema' approach. Their approach is much easier to maintain.